# NoSQL best practice : should I save derivative (calculated data) as it is used in app?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have multiple level deep nested objects including some original data, and then after some user input, calculations are made to the original dataset, and results are kept along with the original data.

Also some other redundant data is stored in the objects by Angular. All this extra data would be easy to programmatically reconstruct by only storing the original data set, the user inputs and some ids..

The easiest (but least economic) version is to store the data as is. This would mean approximately 2-3x size objects, more storage and bandwidth used, etc.

The other version is to store the minimum required data and reconstruct the objects on each query.

The app is not huge (but can grow in the future) and objects aren't either (around 200 keys).

So I'm curious what is best practice to follow in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a balance between over-denormalizing and having an efficient structure in terms of space and complexity (re keeping everything in sync if you do denormalise).

Start with your user stories, the query patterns this will dictate what information is needed in a single document.

It sounds like this is how you've done it anyway.  Embedded sub-docs which you make calculations on during entry.  Keep the calculated values in the parent doc and make sure they're updated with the child records.  Using sub docs means you can update both the calculated values and emebedded sub docs atomically too.

Comment: You are right about keeping a balance. I'll probably just use common sense, and keep the original dataset and whatever else is important for my queries in the docs, and regenerate the rest of the data in the client.

Comment: If the calculations are complex and regularly returned in a user query then I would serialise them in document.  You control access to your documents/data so your DAL/repos can ensure consistency.